# Any good resources to practice efficiency of code modulation?

Tags: binary

I want some resources to practice code efficiency problems like this:
[image: question]

I looked around online and could not find anything. I also looked in two books and only found a section concerning code efficiency. I am not an engineering student but I have a module called communications engineering. I need the resource to prepare for a test. thank you.

Comment: perhaps you can try looking up past papers.

Comment: tlfong01, actually this test was not supposed to include efficiency question like above. Lockdown forced the college to take report based online examination. We got this on sudden notice.

Comment: I see.  So it is not a close book written test, but an open book research project report to submit on line?  Any way, code efficiency belongs on the bigger subject area of algorithm efficiency which in turn is in the area of computer science (courses), studying from basic things such as sorting and searching algorithms. You  remind me that in my days, we used references including the following:  (1) The Art of Computer Programming (Donald Knuth) - Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming, / to continue, ...

Comment: (2) The collected algorithms of the ACM - TR Hopkins, Wiley 2009
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250594439_The_collected_algorithms_of_the_ACM,

(3) Algorithms Efficiency in Sorting - Vassar College
https://www.cs.vassar.edu/~cs125/lectures/lect11-BigOh/ch10.pdf. Good luck to your test. Cheers.

Comment: Uff the notation of the reference solution is very sloppy, to say the least. The question itself is grammatically a bit unsound...  If it helps your self-esteem, this is not a good question and it's not to bad if you don't understand it at first approach.

Comment: Also "binary code" really doesn't mean what your lecture seems to think it means. That doesn't change what they want to read in an exam answer, but just be aware that if you're doing any channel or source coding, or information theory in general, "binary code" is any mapping of an input alphabet to code words, not necessarily of constant length, which are sequences of binary values. The "not of constant length" really is the interesting point here: for example, the usual Huffman Code **is** a binary code, but with an appropriate input distribution can have average word length = entropy in data

Comment: , even for 120 words. Which puts their definition of efficiency to 100%. So, no wonder you couldn't find third-party literature, as their definition of "binary code" is non-canonical.